# translate some word in data json use AngularJS and ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, translation

good day , am try to make flight schedule app use data json , my code already don and work good, but i would like add some translate word to my app mean :

canceled
delayed
scheduled
estimated

this word already in data json i use and update status auto so i want translate this word  data json to another language , mean add some code to work good , like that :

```
    var translations = {
      canceled: 'الغيت',
      delayed: 'تاخرت!',
      scheduled:'مجدولة',
 {
        estimated: 'And it comes with awesome features!'
      }
    };
```

my code :

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('starter.bgw', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngMaterial']);

  app.controller('myctlr', function($scope, $http,$timeout,$ionicLoading) {
    var service_url = "airport.json";
    $http.get(service_url)
      .success(
        function(data) {
$scope.metar= data.result.response.airport.pluginData.weather.metar;
 $scope.time= data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.timestamp;
  $scope.departuretime= data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.departures.timestamp;

 console.log(data);

 dailyData =data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
depr =data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.departures.data;


            $scope.dailyForecast = [];

            for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                 $scope.dailyForecast[i] = {callsign: dailyData[i].flight.identification.number.default,
                                            statu: dailyData[i].flight.status.generic.status.text,
                                            airline: dailyData[i].flight.airline.code.icao,
                                            from: dailyData[i].flight.airport.origin.position.region.city,
                                            timear: dailyData[i].flight.time.scheduled.arrival,
                                            generic: dailyData[i].flight.status.text,




                                            };


            }


             $scope.dep = [];

            for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                 $scope.dep[i] = {callsign: depr[i].flight.identification.number.default,
                                            statu: depr[i].flight.status.generic.status.text,
                                            airline: depr[i].flight.airline.code.icao,
                                            from: depr[i].flight.airport.destination.position.region.city,
                                            timear: depr[i].flight.time.scheduled.departure,
                                            generic: depr[i].flight.status.text,




                                            };


            }




            })


   $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });

  // Set a timeout to clear loader, however you would actually call the $ionicLoading.hide(); method whenever everything is ready or loaded.
  $timeout(function () {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, 2000);

        })








  })();
```

the source code to get the status for flight is

```
statu: dailyData[i].flight.status.generic.status.text,
```

hope some body give me full answer code . thanks

Comment: Can you make clear what the actual problem is?  What is not working?

Comment: every thing work good , but i wand add some code to translate some word in data json to another language

Comment: actually am still thinking how i start

Comment: Ah.  Think some more.  Ping us if you run into a _specific_ problem.